# How to animate a marker smoothly with Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've written a small algorithm that animates markers' movement from
one point to another. The algorithm looks like this in pseudocode:

```
lat_delta = new_lat - old_lat;
lng_delta = new_lng - old_lng;

for(alpha=0; alpha < 1; alpha += 0.1) {
  lat = old_lat + (alpha * lat_delta);
  lng = old_lng + (alpha * lng_delta);
  update_marker(lat, lng);
}
```

The full code is available at http://dev.syskall.com/map/ and
http://dev.syskall.com/map/commute.js.

The problem I have run into is that when the map is zoomed out, the
animation seems to "zig zag". That being said, when you zoom in, the
animation is *much* smoother.

I believe it may be due to the fact that my animation is based on
lat,lng coordinates and not pixels on the screen. When you zoom out, Google Maps is not as
precise and must round the latlng position somehow.

Of course, the current implementation is just fine when the map is zoomed in but not
so good when it's zoomed out.

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes... the api [gives you methods](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapCanvasProjection) to get the pixel co-ords of all your markers on the map. I'd do the following:

> get the pixel co-ords of your marker
>
> render a dummy marker on that spot
>
> remove the original marker
>
> animate your dummy to the new spot
>   using pixel values
>
> place a new map marker on the spot
>
> remove the dummy

At the start and end you can use the api to get latlng from pixels and vice versa.

Comment: The problem is you can only position markers through Latlng objects. Can't set the pizels directly :/

Comment: and converting from pixel co-ords gives me the same problem I'm trying to solve: google does a poor latlng to pixel conversion

Comment: The first issue can be solved by getting the latlang from the pixel coords, for which there is a method... but if you think the quality of conversion is bad then there's not much to be done :(

Comment: But then again, I think Google uses the same conversion functions to position the markers on screen in the first place... so I don't see how the conversion can be sub-standard.